# Is there a Spring boot specific maven plugin to generate a rpm file

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, rpm

I've just started using `Spring Boot` and also have successfully created an rpm file using the *maven* rpm plugin.  This works fine but I was wondering if there is a specific *Spring boot* way to generate an rpm.  In my real usage I will be creating rpm packages with many files in many places (which I currently do with the maven plugin) with many installation scripts and directories.

Comment: Why the maven plugin is not good for you?

Comment: @NiVeR The maven plugin works fine, but if there is a Spring Boot way to do it, I'd like to use that.  We're trying to slowly migrate to Spring Boot and keep the number of different technologies to a minimum if we can.

Comment: Maven and Boot are not comparable things. One is dependency management tool the other development framework. You can use maven with spring boot.

Comment: @NiVeR Point well taken.

Comment: I would say Spring Boot support Maven very good...or the other way around ...